# Private chat (PHP + Socket.io) with PHP Sessions

Tags: php, node.js, redis, socket.io

I am developing a website which uses a private messaging system using php + socket.io.

From the beginning i passed the `sender_id`, `recipient_id` and `text` to socket.io using `socket.emit` but later realized that this could be easily tampered with and wanted to use my php sessions in some way to be sure that the `sender_id` is indeed the `sender_id`.

I have the following setup right now but i dont really understand how to pass the session from index.php to app.js and then connect to redis-server in app.js to get the PHPSESSID which holds the user_id.

- Server 1 running nginx + php-fpm (index.php)
- Server 2 running node.js with socket.io (app.js)
- Server 3 running redis for session management

My code right now looks like the following but is obviously missing the redis part right now which i would really appriciate some help with.

Thanks!

**index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if ($_SESSION['user_id'] == false){
        header("Location:login.php");die;
    }
?>

<script>
var socket = io('https://app01.dev.domain.com:8895');

socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log("Connected to websockets");
});
socket.on('event', function(data){});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){});

$('.chat-message').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    console.log("send message");

    var friend_id = $(this).attr('id');

    friend_id = friend_id.split("-");
    friend_id = friend_id[3];    

    var obj = {
        recipient_id: friend_id, 
        text: $(this).val()
    };

    socket.emit('chat_message', obj);

    $(this).val('');
    return false; 
  }
});
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
var https = require("https"), fs = require("fs");
var options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/cert.pem'),
    ca:     fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/chain.pem')
};
var app = https.createServer(options);
var io = require("socket.io")(app);
var redis = require("redis");

// This i want to fill with for example PHPSESSION:user_id that i get from redis and later use it as sender
// var all_clients = {};

io.set("transports", ["websocket", "polling"]);

io.on("connection", function(client){
    console.log("Client connected");

    // Here i would like to connect to redis in some way and get the user_id but dont really understand how

    //all_clients[USER_ID_FROM_REDIS] = client.id;
    //var user_id = USER_ID_FROM_REDIS;

    client.on("chat_message", function(data){

        var obj = {
            to: data.recipient_id,
            text: data.text
        };        

        console.log("Message inbound from socket: "+client.id+" from: "+data.user_id+" to: "+data.recipient_id+" with text: "+data.text);
    });

    client.on("disconnect", function(){
        console.log("Client disconnected ");
        //delete all_clients[USER_ID_FROM_REDIS];
    });    
});

app.listen(8895, function(){
  console.log("listening on *:8895");
});

var recursive = function () {
  //console.log("Connected clients: "+Object.keys(all_clients).length);
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(all_clients));
  setTimeout(recursive,2000);
}
recursive();
```

Comment: What level of security do you need? What is the [threat model](https://www.tripwire.com/state-of-security/security-data-protection/threat-modeling-10-common-traps-you-dont-want-to-fall-into/).

Comment: @zaph I will not send any crucial data like passwords or stuff like that to socket.io but i would like to make sure that the data can't be tampered with. The redis server will be isolated in production later on.

Comment: @zaph Dont really understand what that means im afraid :( Something like JWT?

Comment: Backing up: tampered with by whom and where, while in transit? A MITM attack?

Comment: @zaph Oh sorry, maybe i was unclear. Not worried about mitm or stuff like that as everything is encrypted. I mean more like the sender itself spoofing his user_id and appears to be some other user sending the events like chat message for example.

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer. Well to solve problem number 2 could i send the user_id with JWT and validate the signature in node.js? Would that be secure enough and maybe smarter than sharing the php session over redis?

Comment: @zaph Thanks, i will try this!

Comment: @zaph This worked just great and safe from tampering by the client. If you want to you can add answer and i will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. HTTP in itself does not protect against MITM attacks, to protect against MITM the server certificate needs to be pined.
2. To protect against a user being spoofed you need authentication such as logging-in or a secret token like Dropbox.
3. Add certificate pinning, that is just jargon for validating that you are connecting to the correct server and not a MITM by verifying the certificate that is sent by the server. MITM used to be harder but WiFi has made it easy to connect to the wrong end-point at Hot Sports, even at home I have seen this.